# leaflet layer control events?

Tags: leaflet

All, I want to detect user layer selection in order to synchronize my sidebar with the displayed layers.

But I don't see any layer control events in the API  reference;  How might I tell when such user layer selection has occurred?

As an alternative, I've looked at the layer load and unload events, but I don't see any identification in what's returned.  Did I miss that somehow?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are some events that let you know when the user activates / desactivates a layer.

This may help you:

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-baselayerchange

For example:

```
map.on('overlayadd', onOverlayAdd);

function onOverlayAdd(e){
    //do whatever
}
```

Comment: That does it.  Thanks!

Comment: Does that fire only when a user manually adds a layer through a control, or *any* time a layer is added--even automatically through code?

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-baselayerchange. Updated @Adrian Garcia's URL

Answer (score 34):

There is a "baselayerchange' event defined  here http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers
Just bind it to the map object and you are good to go.

```
map.on('baselayerchange', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Did not work for me with vue-leaflet. `overlayadd` worked instead

Answer (score 0):

You may bind your own "change" event to the Leaflet layers control radio buttons with jQuery like this:

```
    $("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").change( function () {
        alert('Layers selected: ' + $(this).parent().text());
    });
```

Comment: I was hoping I cd use the native Leaflet, non-JQuery layers control, but I'm beginning to suspect that it's not possible.  Re which kind of layer, I'll be pleased with whatever is available.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried to use it yet, but this plugin looks promising:
https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers

I'm going to give it a shot in one of my projects because this is a very useful function.